# EF Code First Multiplicity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've got the following :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {

        }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }

        [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
        public int UserProfileID { get; set; }

        public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    }
}



public class UserProfile : BaseModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserProfileID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String LastName { get; set; }

        public String LicenseNumber { get; set; }

        public String Position { get; set; }        

        public bool? Active { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
        public String AppUserID { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Division")]
        public int? DivisionID { get; set; }

        public virtual Division Division { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Building> Buildings { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UserProcess> UserProcesses { get; set; }

        public UserProfile()
        {
            Buildings = new HashSet<Building>();
        }

    }
```

I'm getting the error

> 'UserProfile_ApplicationUser_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in
>   Role 'UserProfile_ApplicationUser_Target' in relationship
>   'UserProfile_ApplicationUser'. Because the Dependent Role properties
>   are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the
>   Dependent Role must be '*'."

I don't see what's wrong.  This should be a 1:1 relationship.  An ApplicationUser has a userProfile and UserProfile always has an applicationuser.   Is the way I have it coded making it a 1 to many relationship since multiple user profiles could have an ApplicationUser?   I want to maintain the int key on UserProfile.

Comment: There is no such things as `1:1` in EF.  What you need to build is a 1:0..1` such that only one of the objects has a pointer to the other.  [Configuring 1:1 relationships](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the link.   I added this tot eh model Builder:  modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
            .HasRequired<ApplicationUser>(profile => profile.ApplicationUser);  and removed the UserProfileID from Application User.